# Is it a good habit to empty data structures after you're done using them?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I use various data structures in my programming, and I often transfer data from one structure to another.

```
// assume that I want to transfer all data from v to Q
vector <int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
queue <int> Q;

for(int item : v){
    Q.push(item);
}
// after this point, v is no longer used
```

After you are done using a structure, is it a good habit to empty it? For example, in the above code, should I type `v = {};` after the last comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that would be completely pointless.

Instead, minimise the *scope* of your variables to the places where you need them, so that you literally *cannot* accidentally use them after you intended to; your build will fail.

Do that with functions (preferable), or with additional block scopes:

```
queue <int> Q;

{
   vector <int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   for(int item : v){
       Q.push(item);
   }
}
```

This way you still get the benefit of reclaiming memory, if your containers are absolutely huge and you feel you need to.

Comment: Um, is there a reason you don't put Q inside the block scope? So that its dtor will get called at the end of it?

Comment: @HotelCalifornia Because then you wouldn't be able to use it after performing the copy... The premise of the question is that `Q` goes on to be used, whereas `v` does not.

Comment: oh, of course. Missed that V was the target for cleanup

Answer (score 0):

There is no point doing that.

If you are going to reuse the `vector`, just `v.clear()` it first or consider refactoring the function if it is confusing to know the state of the variables in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

No. When the vector is out of scope the data will be "gone" anyway.

If your `vector` is used in a broader scope, you can use the method `shrink_to_fit` that reduces the capacity of the `vector` and thus it frees additional memory.

More about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/).